# Insert Custom Data into wpusers

Tags: database

I add custom row at my `wp_users` table but the data in the row such as `phone_no` and `ic_no`. But when i try to add data, the data not pass in my table

This is my code

```php
<?php
/*
Template Name: Register
*/
get_header(); 
// Exit if accessed directly
if ( !defined('ABSPATH')) exit;
?>
<html>
    

<body id="login-page" <?php body_class(); ?>>
<div class="container">
<div class="row register-page-container p-3 p-lg-5 mt-5 d-flex justify-content-center w-75 mx-auto">
<?php
global $wpdb, $user_ID;
    
//Check whether the user is already logged in 
if (!$user_ID) {
// Default page shows register form. 
// To show Login form set query variable action=login
$action = (isset($_GET['action']) ) ? $_GET['action'] : 0;
// Login Page
if ($action === "login") { ?>
<?php 
$login = (isset($_GET['login']) ) ? $_GET['login'] : 0;
if ( $login === "failed" ) {
echo '<div class="col-12 register-error"><strong>ERROR:</strong> Invalid username and/or password.</div>';
} elseif ( $login === "empty" ) {
echo '<div class="col-12 register-error"><strong>ERROR:</strong> Username and/or Password is empty.</div>';
} elseif ( $login === "false" ) {
echo '<div class="col-12 register-error"><strong>ERROR:</strong> You are logged out.</div>';
}
?>
<div class="col-md-5">
<?php 
$args = array(
'redirect' => home_url().'/login/', 
);
wp_login_form($args); ?>
<p class="text-center"><a class="mr-2" href="<?php echo wp_registration_url(); ?>">Register Now</a>
<span clas="mx-2">·</span><a class="ml-2" href="<?php echo wp_lostpassword_url( ); ?>" title="Lost Password">Lost Password?</a></p>
</div>
<?php
} else { // Register Page ?>
<?php
if ( $_POST ) {
$error = 0;
    
$username = esc_sql($_REQUEST['username']); 
if ( empty($username) ) {
echo '<div class="col-12 register-error">User name should not be empty.</div>'; 
$error = 1;
}

$email = esc_sql($_REQUEST['email']);
if ( !preg_match("/^[_a-z0-9-]+(\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,4})$/", $email) ) { 
echo '<div class="col-12 register-error">Please enter a valid email.</div>';
$error = 1;
}
    
$phone = esc_sql($_REQUEST['phone']);
if ( empty($phone) ) { 
echo '<div class="col-12 register-error">Please enter a valid phone.</div>';
$error = 1;
}
    
$error = 0; 
$icno = esc_sql($_REQUEST['icno']);
if ( empty($icno) ) { 
echo '<div class="col-12 register-error">Please enter a valid IC No.</div>';
$error = 1;
}   
    
if ( $error == 0 ) {
$password = esc_sql($_REQUEST['password']); 
if ( empty($password) ) {
echo '<div class="col-12 register-error">Password should not be empty.</div>'; 
$error = 1;
}

$username  = $_POST['username'];
$password  = $_POST['password'];
$email   = $_POST['email'];
$phone   = $_POST['phone'];
$icno   = $_POST['icno'];   
$user_data = [
    'user_login' => $username,
    'user_pass'  => $password,
    'user_email'   => $email,
    'phone_no'   => $phone,
    'ic_no'   => $icno,
];
 
$user_id = wp_insert_user( $user_data );
 
// success
if ( ! is_wp_error( $user_id ) ) {
    echo 'User created: ';
}   
 
 else {
 echo 'Registration error';
}
}
}
if ( $error != 2 ) { ?> 
<?php if(get_option('users_can_register')) { ?>
<div class="col-md-5 manual-register-form">
<form action="" method="post"> 
<p> 
<label for="user_login">Username</label>
<input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Type your Username Here" class="register-input mb-4" value="<?php if( ! empty($username) ) echo $username; ?>" /><br />
</p>
<p> 
<label for="user_password">Password</label>
<input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Type your Password Here" class="register-input mb-4" value="<?php if( ! empty($password) ) echo $password; ?>" /><br />
</p>
<p> 
<label for="user_email">Email</label>
<input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Type your Email Here" class="register-input mb-4" value="<?php if( ! empty($email) ) echo $email; ?>" /> <br /> 
</p>
<p> 
<label for="phone_no">Phone</label>
<input type="text" name="phone" placeholder="Type your Phone Here" class="register-input mb-4" value="<?php if( ! empty($phone) ) echo $phone; ?>" /> <br /> 
</p>
<p> 
<label for="ic_no">IC No</label>
<input type="text" name="icno" placeholder="Type your IC No Here" class="register-input mb-4" value="<?php if( ! empty($icno) ) echo $icno; ?>" /> <br /> 
</p>
<input type="submit" id="register-submit-btn" class="mb-4" name="submit" value="SignUp" /> 
</form>
<p>Already have an account? <a href="/login">Login Here</a></p>
</div>
<?php } else {
echo "Registration is currently disabled. Please try again later."; 
}
} ?>
<?php }
} else { ?>
<p>You are logged in. Click <a href="<?php bloginfo('wpurl'); ?>">here to go home</a></p>
<?php } ?>
</div>
</div>
<?php get_footer(); 
?>
</body>
</html>
```

https://codepen.io/rusydi-hakim/pen/GRNMxKY

[image]

Comment: You should not be modifying core tables. If you want to add data to users you should add it as user meta.

Comment: Changing the users table is a massive mistake, storing extra data is what the user meta API and the user meta table is for, columns for social data etc in the user table are only there for backwards compatibility. Never modify WordPress core tables or those extra columns will be destroyed when you update WordPress, and you will loose all that data. I also fixed your Q so that the code is in the question, not on a 3rd party site. There's a lot of missing formatting and lots of broken indentation however

Comment: Okay thanks for the explaining. so i need get_user_meta then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never modify the WordPress core table schemas, such as `wp_users` etc under any circumstances.

**The next time WordPress changes its tables, your custom columns will be destroyed, and all the data will be deleted. This is unavoidable.**

Instead, use the User Meta API and table:

Retrieving a user meta:

```php
$phone = get_user_meta( $user_id, 'phone_number', true );
```

Adding/updating a user meta:

```php
update_user_meta( $user_id, 'phone_number', '0123-456-7890' );
```

Where `$user_id` is the ID of the user

Never modify the tables, store the data in the meta tables instead using the functions.

Comment: So when i use this where the table will show?

Comment: I try using your code. But no value in the table, i change 01234567890 to $phone but when using 0123456789 the data works

Comment: This was not copy paste code, I put those 2 lines in the same block as 2 separate examples so that I didn't have 2 code blocks right next to each other. It is not a single example. If your user does not have a `phone_number` user meta then `$phone` will be empty. It does not retrieve values stored in columns in the user table

Comment: phone_number i already change to my meta. yeh the data not store in the $phone, i will try to adjust